# Changing buttons not working effectively

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an App that hides a button and shows another in the same position (swap) in Ionic when a button is pressed. It works well in doing this until I use a plugin with it and then I have to press the button twice to get the button to swap places.
I was wondering this has to do with some internal process I'm not yet advanced enough to know of and would like some help as to how to fix and explanation.

HTML:

```
<ion-nav-buttons side="right">
   <button class="button" ng-click="readArticle()" ng-if="$root.showStartButton" id="startS">Speech</button>
   <button class="button button-assertive" ng-click="stopReadArticle()" ng-if="$root.showStopButton" id="stopS">Stop</button>
</ion-nav-buttons>
```

Controller:

```
// TTS is the plugin and now I'm trying to hide ($root.showStopButton) and show ($root.showStartButton)
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
            TTS.speak(" ", function () {
                $scope.$root.showStopButton = false;
                $scope.$root.showStartButton = true;
                stepp();
            }, function (reason) {
                console.log(reason);
            });
            }, false);
```

However I have to press the button twice to call this function twice, what's the solution please?

Comment: What plugin you are referring to?

Comment: https://github.com/vilic/cordova-plugin-tts Text to Speech